# Is there a good physical simulation software (mainly refers to the rigid body mechanics simulation)?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, resource-recommendations, computational-physics, simulations, software

I want to simulate the examples in theoretical mechanics and analytical mechanics. I need a mechanical simulation software, which can customize the force field, spring, rigid body, connecting member and other objects. Can you recommend such a software?

For example in the following figure, it is better to simulate the three-dimensional force field：

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/480784/2451